# MongoEngine doesn't see pre-existing records

Tags: python, mongoengine

I set up my model in MongoEngine, and try to query it (I already have a few dozen documents in my collection), but the queryset is empty:

```
>>> mymodel.objects
[]
```

I can add new documents, and those show up in subsequent queries, but there's sign of my preexisting documents:

```
>>> thingy = mymodel(a=2, b=3)
>>> thingy.save()
>>> mymodel.objects
[<mymodel: mymodel object>]
```

What gives? For reference, here's my model definition:

```
from django.conf import settings
from mongoengine import *

connect(settings.MONGO_DATABASE, 
        host=settings.MONGO_HOST, port=settings.MONGO_PORT)

class metadata(Document):

    meta = {'collection': 'metadata'}

    _id   = StringField()
    name  = StringField()
    _type = StringField()
    terms = ListField()
    level = StringField()
    abbreviation  = StringField()
    latest_update = DateTimeField()
    feature_flags = ListField()
    session_details  = DictField()
    legislature_name = StringField()
    lower_chamber_name = StringField()
    upper_chamber_term = IntField()
    upper_chamber_name = StringField()
    lower_chamber_term = IntField()
    lower_chamber_title = StringField()
    upper_chamber_title = StringField()
    _ignored_scraped_sessions = ListField()
```

In case this question gets answered by the author of MongoEngine himself, I wish to express in advance that YOU ARE AWESOME!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the docs answer my question:

To use MongoEngine with existing data, you have to set `allow_inheritance = False` in you model definition, because MongoEngine's inheritance tools set additional attributes on your documents (_cls and _types) and then (evidently) use them to filter MongoEngine queries. The other option may be to add those attributes onto existing documents.

http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html